# Failed to insert in the sequential model layer

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have the script below where I am trying to insert the dataframe into a [sequential model](https://keras.io/guides/sequential_model/), this dataframe is composed by the following structure:

> **m1** = Average of 12 readings (In a window of 60 data) - *Example ((2 + 5 + 7 ...) / 12)*
>
> **d1** = Standard deviation of the 12 data

And so on until it forms *m5, d5 (12x5 = 60)*

> **0-20** = How many times the values ​​are repeated in the range of 0 to 20 in the next 30 readings *(Line 61,62,62 ...)*

And so on until it forms *20-40.40-60.60-80.80-100*

Any suggestions or hints on where I am wrong in the approach?

> Objective is to predict the next 60 readings of the entire dataset

***Script:***

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import operator
import statistics
import collections
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

def histogramNeuronsInput(result):
    """ Generates histogram of input neurons """
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
    for i in range(len(result)):
        data = np.array(result[i])
        x=np.arange(len(data)) + i*6
        # draw averages
        ax.bar(x-0.2, data[:,0], color='C0', width=0.4)
        # draw std
        ax.bar(x+0.2, data[:,1], color='C1', width=0.4)
        # separation line
        if i < len(result) - 1:
            ax.axvline(4.75 + i*6, color='black')
    # turn off xticks
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.legend(labels=['Average', 'Standard deviation'])
    leg = ax.get_legend()
    leg.legendHandles[0].set_color('C0')
    leg.legendHandles[1].set_color('C1')
    plt.title("Histogram: Average versus Standard Deviation")
    plt.ylabel('Consume')
    plt.xlabel('Number of elements (Every 5 is a new block)')

    return plt.show()

def histogramNeuronsOutput(result):
    """ Generates histogram of output neurons """
    colors = ['blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange', 'red']
    labels = ['0-20', '20-40', '40-60', '60-80', '80-100']
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
    for i, data in enumerate(result):
        x = np.arange(len(data)) + i*6
        bars = ax.bar(x, data, color=colors, width=0.4)
        if i == 0:
            for bar, label in zip(bars, labels):
                bar.set_label(label)
        if i < len(result) - 1:
            # separation line after each part, but not after the last
            ax.axvline(4.75 + i*6, color='black')
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_title("Histogram")
    ax.set_ylabel('Consume')
    ax.set_xlabel('Percent')
    plt.show()

def standardDeviation(data):
    """ Calculates standard deviation """
    return statistics.stdev(data)
       
def average(data):
    """ Calculates average """
    return statistics.mean(data)

def captureOcurrences(elements, n):
    """ Capture an X number of elements within a list """
    L = len(elements)
    return [elements[i: i+n] for i in range(0, L, n)]

def neuronsInput(elements):
    """ Generates input neuron modeling (5 averages, 5 standard deviations - Between 12 occurrences in a window of 60 readings) """
    result = []
    temp = []
    start = 0
    limit = 60
    size = int(len(elements))
    TargetDivision = int(size / 30)
    repetitions = 0
    five = 0

    while repetitions < TargetDivision:
        temp = []

        five += 1
        ocurrences = captureOcurrences(elements[start: limit],12)
        for i in ocurrences:
            print("[INFO] 12 Ocurrences: {}".format(i))
            print("[INFO] Average: {}".format(average(i)))
            m = average(i)
            print("[INFO] Standard Deviation: {}".format(standardDeviation(i)))
            sd = standardDeviation(i)
            print("Result: [{},{}]\n\n".format(m,sd))
            temp.append([m,sd])

        print("[INFO] Cycle Result {}: \n{}\n\n".format(repetitions+1,result))
        print(temp)
        result.append(temp)

        repetitions += 1
        limit += 10
        start += 10

    print("[INFO] Final result of phase Neurons Input: \n{}\n".format(result))
    return result

def neuronsOutput(elements):
    """ Generates output neuron modeling (Histogram of the next 30 data readings) """
    result = []
    start = 61
    limit = 90
    size = int(len(elements))
    TargetDivision = int(size / 30)
    repetitions = 0

    while repetitions < TargetDivision:

        print("[INFO] Reading [{}:{}]".format(start, limit))
        print("[INFO] Elements:\n{}".format(elements[start: limit]))
        counter=collections.Counter(elements[start: limit])
        
        consumption0_20 = 0
        consumption20_40 = 0
        consumption40_60 = 0
        consumption60_80 = 0
        consumption80_100 = 0
        for key in counter:
            if key <= 20:
                consumption0_20 += int(counter[key])
            elif key > 20 and key < 40:
                consumption20_40 += int(counter[key])
            elif key > 40 and key < 60:
                consumption40_60 += int(counter[key])
            elif key > 60 and key < 80:
                consumption60_80 += int(counter[key])
            elif key > 80 and key < 100:
                consumption80_100 += int(counter[key])

        print("[INFO] Histogram: 0-20 [{}], 20-40 [{}], 40-60 [{}], 60-80 [{}], 80-100 [{}]\n\n".format(consumption0_20,consumption20_40,consumption40_60,consumption60_80,consumption80_100))

        result.append([consumption0_20,consumption20_40,consumption40_60,consumption60_80,consumption80_100])

        repetitions += 1
        limit += 10
        start += 10

    print("[INFO] Final result of phase Neurons Output: \n{}\n".format(result))
    return result

def binaryInput(data):
    """ I divided the values ​​of each column by the highest occurrence in the column """
    max_average = 0
    max_deviation = 0
    for j in range(len(data[0])):
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i][j][0] > max_average:
                max_average = data[i][j][0]
            if data[i][j][1] > max_deviation:
                max_deviation = data[i][j][1]
        for p in range(len(data)):
            if max_average != 0:
                data[p][j][0] = round(data[p][j][0] / max_average, 3)
            if max_deviation != 0:
                data[p][j][1]  = round(data[p][j][1] / max_deviation, 3)
        max_average = 0
        max_deviation = 0
    return data

def binaryOutput(data):
    """ I divided the values ​​of each column by the highest occurrence in the column """
    max_consume = 0
    for j in range(len(data[0])):
        for i in range(len(data)):
            if data[i][j] > max_consume:
                max_consume = data[i][j]
        for p in range(len(data)):
            if max_consume != 0:
                data[p][j] = round(data[p][j] / max_consume, 3)
        max_consume = 0
    return data

def conversionDataframe(dataNeuronInput,dataNeuronOutput):
    """ Converts data to a dataframe pandas """
    ni = pd.DataFrame(data= dataNeuronInput)
    ni.columns = ['m1,d1', 'm2,d2', 'm3,d3', 'm4,d4', 'm5,d5']

    no = pd.DataFrame(data= dataNeuronOutput)
    no.columns = ['0-20', '20-40', '40-60', '60-80', '80-100']

    return pd.concat([ni, no], axis=1)

def modeling(data):
    """ Generates the initial model for training the neural network """
    readings = data.iloc[:, 1].values

    dataNeuronInput = neuronsInput(readings)
    #histogramNeuronsInput(dataNeuronInput)

    dataNeuronOutput = neuronsOutput(readings)
    #histogramNeuronsOutput(dataNeuronOutput)

    dataFrameNoBinary = conversionDataframe(dataNeuronInput, dataNeuronOutput)
    print("[INFO] Viewing non-binary data: \n{}\n\n".format(dataFrameNoBinary))

    binaryNeuronInput = binaryInput(dataNeuronInput)
    print(binaryNeuronInput)
    binaryNeuronOutput = binaryOutput(dataNeuronOutput)
    print(binaryNeuronOutput)
    dataFrameBinary = conversionDataframe(binaryNeuronInput, binaryNeuronOutput)
    print("[INFO] Converting to binary data frame: \n{}\n\n".format(dataFrameBinary))

    return dataFrameBinary

def neural():

    df = modeling(pd.read_csv('/home/user/Desktop/classification/data/minute.csv'))

    # Define Sequential model with 3 layers
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
            layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
            layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
        ]
    )
    # Call model on a test input
    x = tf.ones((3, 3))
    y = model(df)

def main():
    """ Initializes the script """
    print("[INFO] Start *******************************************************************************")
    neural()
    print("[INFO] End *********************************************************************************")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***Data Frame Head and dtypes:***

```
             m1,d1           m2,d2           m3,d3           m4,d4           m5,d5   0-20  20-40  40-60  60-80  80-100
0   [0.573, 0.699]  [0.412, 0.224]  [0.696, 0.512]  [0.326, 0.314]   [0.79, 0.685]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
1   [0.456, 0.251]  [0.629, 0.523]  [0.344, 0.286]    [0.8, 0.699]    [0.721, 1.0]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
2   [0.658, 0.531]  [0.339, 0.282]  [0.592, 0.614]    [0.859, 1.0]  [0.365, 0.283]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
3   [0.396, 0.314]   [0.29, 0.201]      [1.0, 1.0]   [0.34, 0.288]  [0.886, 0.647]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
4   [0.379, 0.315]      [1.0, 1.0]  [0.302, 0.248]  [0.929, 0.655]  [0.328, 0.308]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
5       [1.0, 1.0]  [0.274, 0.249]  [0.679, 0.536]   [0.52, 0.413]  [0.382, 0.337]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
6   [0.657, 0.898]  [0.324, 0.244]  [0.796, 0.565]  [0.336, 0.337]   [0.594, 0.48]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
7   [0.397, 0.312]  [0.731, 0.583]  [0.358, 0.296]  [0.586, 0.495]  [0.263, 0.228]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
8   [0.792, 0.589]  [0.343, 0.296]  [0.472, 0.434]  [0.278, 0.227]  [0.432, 0.316]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
9   [0.395, 0.366]  [0.301, 0.247]  [0.449, 0.413]  [0.438, 0.324]  [0.798, 0.545]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
10  [0.411, 0.347]  [0.436, 0.417]  [0.373, 0.276]   [0.78, 0.565]  [0.399, 0.274]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
11  [0.521, 0.443]  [0.221, 0.206]  [0.658, 0.476]   [0.512, 0.35]  [0.364, 0.264]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
12  [0.277, 0.271]  [0.364, 0.264]  [0.729, 0.477]  [0.325, 0.265]  [0.544, 0.447]  0.964    1.0      0      0       0
13  [0.409, 0.312]  [0.693, 0.484]  [0.333, 0.234]  [0.551, 0.458]  [0.297, 0.246]  0.964    1.0      0      0       0
14  [0.728, 0.487]  [0.332, 0.233]  [0.439, 0.403]  [0.309, 0.245]  [0.327, 0.231]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
15  [0.368, 0.287]  [0.279, 0.229]   [0.46, 0.396]  [0.309, 0.235]  [0.854, 0.675]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
16  [0.342, 0.283]  [0.454, 0.397]  [0.268, 0.203]  [0.888, 0.685]  [0.208, 0.117]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
17  [0.492, 0.422]  [0.238, 0.201]  [0.676, 0.585]  [0.329, 0.233]   [0.24, 0.147]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
18  [0.311, 0.272]  [0.389, 0.468]  [0.567, 0.433]   [0.21, 0.145]  [0.561, 0.435]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
19  [0.456, 0.485]  [0.518, 0.447]  [0.223, 0.131]  [0.552, 0.447]  [0.254, 0.185]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
20  [0.689, 0.597]   [0.23, 0.126]  [0.386, 0.392]    [0.363, 0.2]  [0.276, 0.211]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
21  [0.202, 0.129]  [0.228, 0.158]  [0.503, 0.376]  [0.258, 0.215]  [0.813, 0.551]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
22  [0.248, 0.173]  [0.493, 0.379]  [0.232, 0.187]  [0.804, 0.571]  [0.295, 0.223]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
23  [0.484, 0.392]   [0.216, 0.18]   [0.583, 0.46]   [0.46, 0.342]  [0.281, 0.226]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
24  [0.255, 0.215]  [0.311, 0.288]  [0.658, 0.444]  [0.248, 0.227]  [0.582, 0.523]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
25  [0.357, 0.316]  [0.619, 0.456]    [0.258, 0.2]   [0.562, 0.54]   [0.29, 0.235]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
26    [0.71, 0.49]  [0.246, 0.199]   [0.45, 0.473]  [0.314, 0.237]  [0.343, 0.235]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
27  [0.284, 0.247]  [0.256, 0.227]  [0.484, 0.458]  [0.308, 0.239]   [0.842, 0.54]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
28  [0.316, 0.272]   [0.476, 0.46]  [0.268, 0.206]   [0.835, 0.56]  [0.296, 0.168]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
29  [0.529, 0.483]  [0.225, 0.202]   [0.602, 0.45]  [0.433, 0.314]  [0.291, 0.187]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
30  [0.288, 0.273]  [0.324, 0.247]   [0.647, 0.45]  [0.256, 0.182]  [0.743, 0.572]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
31   [0.37, 0.292]  [0.619, 0.459]   [0.268, 0.16]  [0.589, 0.532]  [0.569, 0.341]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
32  [0.688, 0.479]  [0.266, 0.158]   [0.451, 0.47]  [0.579, 0.344]  [0.426, 0.234]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
33  [0.259, 0.174]  [0.237, 0.159]  [0.696, 0.495]  [0.421, 0.231]  [0.855, 0.551]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
34  [0.261, 0.193]   [0.67, 0.502]  [0.375, 0.197]  [0.714, 0.511]  [0.566, 0.401]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
35  [0.635, 0.509]  [0.394, 0.199]   [0.571, 0.45]   [0.515, 0.39]   [0.421, 0.28]  0.964    1.0      0      0       0
36  [0.419, 0.231]   [0.36, 0.232]  [0.648, 0.499]   [0.405, 0.28]  [0.551, 0.452]  0.964    1.0      0      0       0
37   [0.409, 0.28]  [0.659, 0.496]  [0.357, 0.235]  [0.531, 0.464]   [0.308, 0.25]  0.964    1.0      0      0       0
38    [0.741, 0.5]  [0.343, 0.238]   [0.414, 0.41]  [0.324, 0.247]  [0.531, 0.438]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
39  [0.393, 0.291]  [0.249, 0.213]  [0.468, 0.403]  [0.336, 0.256]    [1.0, 0.588]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
40   [0.322, 0.27]  [0.452, 0.407]   [0.293, 0.22]    [1.0, 0.612]  [0.346, 0.247]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
41    [0.5, 0.427]  [0.243, 0.215]  [0.739, 0.508]   [0.479, 0.35]  [0.278, 0.161]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
42  [0.307, 0.285]  [0.469, 0.399]  [0.678, 0.449]  [0.248, 0.159]  [0.801, 0.708]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
43   [0.51, 0.428]  [0.655, 0.456]  [0.257, 0.142]  [0.804, 0.724]   [0.23, 0.144]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
44   [0.726, 0.47]   [0.245, 0.14]  [0.501, 0.618]   [0.44, 0.299]   [0.276, 0.17]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
45  [0.288, 0.226]  [0.215, 0.121]   [0.68, 0.625]  [0.249, 0.171]  [0.701, 0.716]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
46  [0.229, 0.148]  [0.683, 0.624]  [0.222, 0.146]  [0.687, 0.732]  [0.296, 0.184]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0
47  [0.646, 0.627]  [0.204, 0.152]  [0.542, 0.632]   [0.36, 0.224]  [0.291, 0.215]  1.000    0.5      0      0       0

m1,d1      object
m2,d2      object
m3,d3      object
m4,d4      object
m5,d5      object
0-20      float64
20-40     float64
40-60       int64
60-80       int64
80-100      int64
```

> ***Input layer:*** *[m1,d1], [m2,d2], [m3,d3], [m4,d4], [m5,d5]*
>
> ***Output layer:*** *0-20, 20-40, 40-60, 60-80, 80-100*

***Error:***

```
Call initializer instance with the dtype argument instead of passing it to the constructor Traceback (most recent call last):   File "script.py", line 233, in <module>
    main()   File "script.py", line 229, in main
    neural()   File "script.py", line 223, in neural
    y = layer(df)   File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 676, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)   File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1865, in _maybe_build
    self.input_spec, inputs, self.name)   File "/home/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 109, in assert_input_compatibility
    if x.shape.ndims is None: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndims'
```

**Note:** For observation only, **data.csv** consists of 1440 rows, with two columns, date and value, where the date varies in the range of `1 minute` *(1 day = 1440 minutes)* and the value in the range `0 to 100` *(Consumption of CPU)*

[CSV FIle](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/268c65eefb7bf6c2b1ef5fe00b6e383c/data.csv)

Comment: Your code does not match with the error, we can see in the traceback that the code is different from what you provided

Comment: Your model input should be 1D array, but you have 2D array. I guess it's the mismatch. Post you code about how are you giving input and output to your model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy and Rahul, I added all the code and CSV file in the question

Comment: Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pointing out the key problems of the code below:

1. You are trying to feed a `dataframe` into a neural network. This is not possible. Inputs to a Keras architecture must be passed by a NumPy matrix.
2. In `sequential` model, the shape of features must be denoted in the first layer of the sequential model by a parameter `input_shape`.
3. The output of the model must be the same as the number of nodes in the last dense layer of a sequential model.

I have corrected the code assuming that I have to predict the `mi, ri` of `(i+1)'th` time. Where I am given the `mi ri` values of the previous time `i`. The code is given below.

```
def neural():

    df = modeling(pd.read_csv('./data.csv'))
    # only taking 'mi' and 'di' inputs for simplicity
    ndf = df.to_numpy()[:, :5]

    # ndf matrix contains python lists, it must be broken into floats
    temp = []
    for a in ndf:
        for b in a:
            temp.append(b)
    ndf = (np.array(temp)).reshape((48, 10))

    # Converting data matrix in such a form that we are given an input of i'th 
    # time, and have to predict for (i+1)'th time
    X = np.array([ndf[i, :] for i in range(0, ndf.shape[0]-1)])
    y = np.array([ndf[i, :] for i in range(1, ndf.shape[0])])
    print('input-output shape', X.shape, y.shape)
    
    # Define Sequential model with 3 layers
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [   
            # First layer of a sequential model must contain a input_shape
            # that defines the features
            layers.Dense(2, activation="relu", name="layer1", input_shape=X.shape[1:]),
            layers.Dense(3, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
            # The last layer of a sequential model should be equal to the number of
            # outputs, in this case : 5*2 = 10  (5 [mi, di] pairs)
            layers.Dense(10, name="layer3"),
        ]
    )

    # Compile the model and define a loss function (loss function generates 
    # penalty for a wrong output)
    model.compile(loss='mse')
    # Check the architecture of the model (you may skip this line)
    model.summary()
    # The training
    model.fit(X, y, batch_size=8, epochs=2)
```

Although, this does not satisfy what you are trying to do. Therefore, I would like to give some hint. You are trying to predict a sequence of future values, given a sequence of values of a previous time. In my opinion, you should try out implementing a Recurrent architecture (my best choice LSTM). I hope this should be appropriate for the problem. Feel free to reply for any further query. Thanks.

Comment: I did some tests with LSTM I would like to do with both and compare which is the best result

Comment: Execution returned this to: `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 40 into shape (48,10)`

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: Array resize must be appropriate. For your dataset, if you have 20 rows of data, then you should reshape it to (20, 10). Looking through te error, I believe you executed the code with different csv file that had 4 rows. Therefore this error may be solved by giving it reshape value of (4, 10).

Comment: The fault was mine, I put the wrong CSV, after using the question, I received this error: `TypeError: compile () missing 1 required positional argument: 'optimizer'
`

Comment: Can I use `optimizer = 'Adam'`?

Comment: Yes, please. I believe Keras by default uses RMSprop optimizer. But somehow the version you are using does not contain any default optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your function neuron.

Sequential model does not take inputs directly from pandas dataframe. So, firstly convert your data into a numpy array.

You cannot directly predict without training, so you have to firstly train your model. Then you can use your model for predictions.

Here's the corrected function:

```
def neural():

    df = modeling(pd.read_csv('data.csv'))
    
    # Convert Data into numpy arrays
    X = np.array(df['m1,d1'].values.tolist())
    X = np.append(X, np.array(df['m2,d2'].values.tolist()), axis = 1)
    X = np.append(X, np.array(df['m3,d3'].values.tolist()), axis = 1)
    X = np.append(X, np.array(df['m4,d4'].values.tolist()), axis = 1)
    X = np.append(X, np.array(df['m5,d5'].values.tolist()), axis = 1)
    print(X)
    
    Y = []
    Y.append(np.asarray(df['0-20'], dtype=np.float32))
    Y.append(np.asarray(df['20-40'], dtype=np.float32))
    Y.append(np.asarray(df['40-60'], dtype=np.float32))
    Y.append(np.asarray(df['60-80'], dtype=np.float32))
    Y = np.transpose(np.asarray(Y))
    print(Y)
    
    # Define Sequential model with 3 layers
    model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            layers.Dense(16, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
            layers.Dense(8, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
            layers.Dense(4, name="layer3"),
        ]
    )
    # Compile and train the model
    model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'mse', metrics = ['mae'])
    model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 100, batch_size = 4)
    
    # Use the model for predictions
    # This is the first input of your dataset which I have used for prediction
    # Your input should be of shape (No.of examples you are predicting, 10)
    x = [[0.573, 0.69, 0.412, 0.224, 0.696, 0.512, 0.326, 0.314, 0.79, 0.685]]
    y = model.predict(x)
    print(y)
    # Output is [[ 1.0625525e+00  5.0397384e-01  2.1531060e-04 -1.0078825e-02]] which is very close to the actual output, but you should test on unseen data, it will be better.
```

I have improved the model, but you should check it with large dataset, so that there is no overfitiing or other problems.

Comment: Could you explain to me why keeping x = [[0.573, 0.69, 0.412, 0.224, 0.696, 0.512, 0.326, 0.314, 0.79, 0.685]]? Please!

Comment: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [10,1], In[1]: [10,16]
  [[{{node sequential/layer1/Relu}}]]
`

Comment: The execution returned this for: `y = model.predict (x)`

Comment: any suggestion ?

Comment: I have a large data set for testing

Comment: [[0.573, 0.69, 0.412, 0.224, 0.696, 0.512, 0.326, 0.314, 0.79, 0.685]] these are values for [[m1, d1, m2, d2, ......, m5, d5]]. y = model.predict (x) this is used to predict output for given input x. The input to dense layer is 1D array, so I have converted everything to 1D array. If you want to use 2D or 3D arrays, then try using Convolution and Flatten layers.

Comment: If you have large dataset then divide it into training, validation and testing set. Then using it, you could create a better model.